# New document does not default save to correct location

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document

In sharepoint, I have created a new document library and have attached a template so that users can upload new documents with that template.

When the user clicks New > MyDocument it opens up the "MyDocument" template correctly - all the fields are there.

There are two problems, however:
1. The default save location is not correct: pressing CTRL + S attempts to save the document to "My documents" on the local PC, instead of the correct sharepoint folder. The user, knowing the URL can enter this manually, but is there a way to automate the process?
2. The DIP panel is not opening by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the website to the intranet sites in internet options solved the problem.

Internet Options > Security > Sites > Local Intranet, Advanced > Add > Close

After doing this, make sure to restart the browser.
This solved both problems (1, 2).